# How do I update an unmanaged package via Github fork?

Tags: unmanaged-package, github

I have installed ActionPlans v3 from AppExchange. The package is unmanaged, but it provides a lot of functionality that I need. Unfortunately, after the install, I am unable to push new changes to production, as the app fails a whole battery of tests.

After browsing the forums and reading AppExchange reviews, it's suggested that there are updated [forks on GitHub](https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/ActionPlans/network) addressing the code coverage issues.

How do I push these changes to my org?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload metadata from github fork and deploy it to your sandbox with Migration Tool or workbench tool. Or any other tool that allow to deploy metadata. After that you can check your unit tests. After that you can upload change set. If it had fixed test issues it would be successfully deployed to prod environment